# Error on webView reload on iOS 8 after was working on iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, ios8

I have iPhone app that works on iOS < 7 good, after upgrated to iOS 8 my app crashes on the next error:

I'm using webView to display big part of my app, after few changes I check if pass X minutes, if NO I dont do anything and continue displaying the current page, but If YES what I do is to initilize it from start :

```
 UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    CDVViewController *rootViewController = (CDVViewController *)window.rootViewController;

    [rootViewController.webView reload];
```

on the `reload` I get crash + error :

```
-[_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController webView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17de2800

2014-09-21 11:56:43.719 myapp4[803:191017] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController webView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17de2800'
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

**ADDED:**

to reload the `webView` I'm calling a method in `SessionManager` object from `AppDelegate`, that should to the job:

```
AppDelegate.m
[SessionManager reload]
```

in `SessionManager` the method is doing all what I wrote in the begging.

I tried to enter the call to `webView` from `AppDelegate` and it worked:

```
[viewController.webView reload]
```

but I don't want to change a lot the Session logic in `AppDelegate` and prefer doing it on `SessionManager`...can I still call it from the `SessionManager` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few design problems on the code that you are using, however let's start describing the crash.

The problem is pretty clear from the crash: the `rootViewController` that you have in that case is not the `CDVViewController` that you are expecting, but it is a `_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController` (it's a new class used on iOS 8 to display alert views).

So what it happens is that you are not getting the `rootController` that you expected on iOS 8, this may be caused because of how you set `rootViewController` or just because the window retrieved with `keyWindow` is not the window you expect (I would need some more log to see exactly what's going on). So calling the `webView` property on a controller that is not your controller with that public property causes the crash.

To solve the problem, you may want to design your code in a better way.
What you want to achieve is to refresh the webView on CDVViewController, here some possible approaches:

- The controller could handle this update itself, without relying on an external object. If this solution is ok for your use case, you should trigger the update directly on your controller, really easy to achieve.
- However there might be cases where you want to manage this update externally, let's say from another object called `UpdateManager` in that case, when you want to update the page you should trigger a notification from the `UpdateManager`, so that your controller can observe that notification reacting accordingly. If you are not used to notifications, you can read more [here](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/). Similarly you could use the delegation pattern (you can read more about it [here](http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002)) to communicate when a refresh should be triggered.
- Alternatively a "quick and dirty" way to solve is to provide to this external object a reference to the controller, so that you don't need to rely on the window object to obtain the controller that you are looking for.
  Something like `_updateManager.controller = myController;`
  And you may want to create an external public method (maybe `triggerReload` instead of exposing the `webView` calling a method on it).

EDIT: Since it looks like you need some more help, I'll summarise the steps here for the "quick and dirty" way to solve.

1. Create a property called `CDVViewController  *webViewController` on your `SessionManager`
2. When you initialize the `CDVViewController`, set this property, something like 
   `CDVViewController *myViewController = [[CDVViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CDVViewController bundle:nil];
   [SessionManager sharedInstance].webViewController = myViewController;`
3. Now on the `reload` method of the `SessionManager` you can use the property `webViewController` instead of relying on `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController`

Comment: Well I'm displaying an `UIAlertView` on top of the `webView` and before iOS8 I was using that code and was getting the `CDVViewController` , now I understand that I'm getting the `alertView`. could you advise me how to fix it without changing the design of the all project? because when I call this method without the `UIAlertView` it works fine,

Comment: Maybe I cant get the `CDVViewController`  after changing `(CDVViewController *)window.rootViewController;`. what more logs you asking to help answering this question?

Comment: The quick and dirty way to solve is basically described in the last sentence of my answer, you need to give to the object that is triggering the update a reference to your controller. Who is this object? It is the appDelegate? If so, you should have a reference to the `CDVViewController`, just save it on a property for later use

Comment: I added some data in my original question that answer your comment

Comment: I already explained to you the exact way to solve, I just edited again with a few steps to clarify even more.